# Include Jiffy in my Cowboy server

Tags: json, erlang, cowboy, jiffy

I've tried following [Erlang: How to include libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26662424/erlang-how-to-include-libraries)

but the answers don't work for me. I cloned jiffy into deps/jiffy
I'm using `gmake run` to run.

My Makefile

```
PROJECT = erlapp
PROJECT_DESCRIPTION = New project
PROJECT_VERSION = 0.1.0

DEPS = cowboy
dep_cowboy_commit = master

include erlang.mk
```

How do I include jiffy as a dependency too, so it loads and I can use it in my project?

Answer (score 0):

Try to check [doc](https://erlang.mk/guide/building.html)

And try

```
DEPS = cowboy jiffy

dep_jiffy = git https://github.com/davisp/jiffy
```

Comment: I tried that. Error: No Makefile to build dependency /Users/me/erlapp/deps/jiffy.

Comment: check https://github.com/davisp/jiffy - Makefile exists. Can you pastle output from you jiffy directory?